# Determining the convergence of $\alpha_n=\frac{6\cdot3^n-4\lambda^n}{3^{n+1}+2\cdot\lambda^n}$ when $\lambda>3$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We are told to examine the sequence
$$\alpha_n=\frac{6\cdot3^n-4\lambda^n}{3^{n+1}+2\cdot\lambda^n},\quad(λ>0)$$ in terms of convergence. We take $3$ possible cases: $\lambda=3, \lambda>3, \lambda<3$.

I don't understand what it shows in the second case, when $\lambda>3$:

$$\alpha_n=\frac{6\cdot(3/\lambda)^n-4}{3\cdot(3/\lambda)^n+2}$$

After that, it just takes the limit of the above and it's understandable, but I really don't get what algebra was used to get the above in the first place.

Comment: Did you mean $3^{n+1}$ instead of $3n+1$ in the first expression? Otherwise the two expressions are not equal!

Comment: Yes you are correct, i will edit

Comment: Are you asking why $\dfrac{6\cdot3^n-4λ^n}{3^{n+1}+2\cdotλ^n}$ is equal to $\dfrac{6\cdot(3/λ)^n-4}{3\cdot(3/λ)^n+2}$?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, in the case where $λ>3$

Comment: Just divide numerator and denominator by $\lambda^n$, and use $3^{n+1} = 3 \cdot 3^n$.

Comment: @HansLundmark i see, thank you